# Совместить input radio и a href

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть такой код в котором содержатся input radio и всплывающие окно:

```css
#donate {
    margin:4px;
   width:100%;
    float:left;
 height:10%;
}

#donate label {
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    margin:4px;
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:2px dashed #777;
    cursor:pointer;
height:30px; 
}

#donate label span {
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding:5px 0px;
    display:block;
}

#donate label input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
}

#donate input:checked + span {
    background-color:#404040;
    color:#F7F7F7;
 border-radius:5px;
}

#donate .yellow {
    background-color:#edc951;
    color:white;
}


#zatemnenie {
        background: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.5);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: none;
      }
      #okno {
        width: 300px;
        height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 15px;
        border: 3px solid #0000cc;
        border-radius: 10px;
        color: #0000cc;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: auto;
        background: #fff;
      }
      #zatemnenie:target {display: block;}
      .close {
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid #0000cc;
        color: #0000cc;
        padding: 0 12px;
        margin: 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
        background: #f2f2f2;
        font-size: 14pt;
        cursor:pointer;
      }
      .close:hover {background: #e6e6ff;}
```

```html
<div id="donate">
    <label class="yellow"><input type="radio" name="sposob"><span>Стол</a></span></label>
    <label class="yellow"><input type="radio" name="sposob"><span>На вынос</span></label>
    <label class="yellow"><input type="radio" name="sposob"><span>Доставка</span></label>
</div>
<div id="zatemnenie">
      <div id="okno">
        Всплывающее окошко!<br>
        <a href="#" class="close">Закрыть окно</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#zatemnenie">Всплывающее окно</a>
```

Как можно совместить всплывающие окно и input radio?
Что бы при нажатии на "Стол" открывалось всплывающие окно.

Comment: Есть, но его надо написать. JavaScript  вам нужен также для этой задачи. Гляньте в сторону событий к примеру

Comment: Я конечно понимаю, что html+css легче в освоении, но завязывайте с этим - используйте js для таких задач. `:target` - это вообще финиш, могли бы на chekcbox'e сделать.

Comment: @L.F.C. есть ссылкочки на примеры?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events

Answer (score 0):

```css
#donate {
    margin:4px;
   width:100%;
    float:left;
 height:10%;
}

#donate label {
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    margin:4px;
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:2px dashed #777;
    cursor:pointer;
height:30px; 
}

#donate label span {
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding:5px 0px;
    display:block;
}

#donate label input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
}

#donate input:checked + span {
    background-color:#404040;
    color:#F7F7F7;
 border-radius:5px;
}

#donate .yellow {
    background-color:#edc951;
    color:white;
}


#zatemnenie {
        background: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.5);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: none;
      }
      #okno {
        width: 300px;
        height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 15px;
        border: 3px solid #0000cc;
        border-radius: 10px;
        color: #0000cc;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: auto;
        background: #fff;
      }
      #zatemnenie:target {display: block;}
      .close {
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid #0000cc;
        color: #0000cc;
        padding: 0 12px;
        margin: 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
        background: #f2f2f2;
        font-size: 14pt;
        cursor:pointer;
      }
      .close:hover {background: #e6e6ff;}
```

```html
<div id="donate">
   <label class="yellow"><input type="radio" name="sposob" onclick="location.href = '#zatemnenie';"><span>Стол</a></span></label>
    <label class="yellow"><input type="radio" name="sposob"><span>На вынос</span></label>
    <label class="yellow"><input type="radio" name="sposob"><span>Доставка</span></label>
</div>
<div id="zatemnenie">
      <div id="okno">
        Всплывающее окошко!<br>
        <a href="#" class="close">Закрыть окно</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#zatemnenie">Всплывающее окно</a>
```